# Angular-timer - Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I followed all the steps to install angular-timer and it works correctly in the development build but when I try to do a production build (minified, concatinated) I get an

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: how are you defining your controllers?

Comment: I'm not adding anything to the controller, I use the <timer end-time="1420070400000">{{days}} days, {{hours}} hours, {{minutes}} minutes, {{seconds}} seconds.</timer> directive

Answer (score 0):

please just make sure that you are defining your controllers "safe for Minification", you can either definde your dependencies using the $inject service or you can define your dependencies as text in your controller definitions.

I'm quoting the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) here:

> Since Angular infers the controller's dependencies from the names of
>   arguments to the controller's constructor function, if you were to
>   minify the JavaScript code for your controller, all of its
>   function arguments would be minified as well, and the dependency
>   injector would not be able to identify services correctly.

**Using $inject:**

```
function myCtrl($scope, $http) {...}
myCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];
app.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);
```

**Inline annotation**

```
function myCtrl($scope, $http) {...}
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', myCtrl]);
```

Comment: I am using the inline annotation, but I also created a new project with an empty controller and I still get the error. As I said before there is no need to add any extra js. https://db.tt/2NLGt896